# Spotify iOS SDK - No background play

Tags: ios, spotify

I can't get the Spotify iOS SDK working with background play so that track continue to play when the phone is locked or the application is no longer active.

I have `UIBackgroundModes` in my `Info.plist` set up as so:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>audio</string>
    <string>fetch</string>
</array>
```

Is there something else I'm missing or something I need to enable when setting up the SDK in app?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To fix this I had to extend my class to implement the `SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate` and write to functions to activate and deactivate the `AVAudioSession`

Step 1

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didChangePlaybackStatus isPlaying: Bool) {
    if isPlaying {
        self.activateAudioSession()
    } else {
        self.deactivateAudioSession()
    }
}
```

Step 2

```
// MARK: Activate audio session

func activateAudioSession() {
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
}

// MARK: Deactivate audio session

func deactivateAudioSession() {
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have done it before in one of my previous apps. Think you need to configure audio session right after app launch.

Here is a bit of code showing how to do that. But it's written in Objective C.

```
- (void) initializeAudioSession
{
    // Registers this class as the delegate of the audio session to listen for audio interruptions  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(audioRouteChanged:)
                                                 name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification
                                               object: [AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];

    //Set the audio category of this app to playback (allows music to play in background)
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error: &setCategoryError];
    if (setCategoryError) {
        //RESPOND APPROPRIATELY
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error: %@", setCategoryError);
    }

    // An instance of the audio player/manager is passed to the listener
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioRouteChanged:) name:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification object:nil];

    //Activate the audio session
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationError];
    if (activationError) {
        //RESPOND APPROPRIATELY
        NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error: %@", activationError);
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Audio session callbacks

-(void)audioRouteChanged:(NSNotification*)audioChanged;
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [audioChanged userInfo];
    int routeChangeReason = (int)[userInfo objectForKey:AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey];

    if ([SpotifyPlayer sharedPlayer].isPlaying) {
        if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable)
        {
            [[SpotifyPlayer sharedPlayer] setIsPlaying:false callback:nil];
        }
    }
}

void audioRouteChangeListenerCallback (void *inUserData, AudioSessionPropertyID inPropertyID, UInt32 inPropertyValueSize, const void *inPropertyValue)
{
    if (inPropertyID != kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange) return;


    CFDictionaryRef routeChangeDictionary = inPropertyValue;
    CFNumberRef routeChangeReasonRef = CFDictionaryGetValue (routeChangeDictionary, CFSTR (kAudioSession_AudioRouteChangeKey_Reason));

    SInt32 routeChangeReason;
    CFNumberGetValue (routeChangeReasonRef, kCFNumberSInt32Type, &routeChangeReason);

    // "Old device unavailable" indicates that a headset was unplugged, or that the
    //  device was removed from a dock connector that supports audio output.
    if (routeChangeReason == kAudioSessionRouteChangeReason_OldDeviceUnavailable)
    {
        [[SpotifyPlayer sharedPlayer] setIsPlaying:false callback:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Christian. I'm just wondering why all of this would be necessary when it isn't anywhere in Spotify's example project which works with background audio?

Comment: @ja Are you sure it's not doing anything? Which example are you referring to?

Comment: I'm referring to the example project included in the SDK download. Turns out they do have something that activates the AVAudioSession, although why it's not part of the default behaviour seems confusing to me

Comment: I guess some apps needs to stop playing when it's sent to background. Maybe a decision to make the SDK fit to all of scenarios.

Comment: I suppose, but then you would just the disable the background mode in the .plist file. Anyway, thanks for the help!